# How do I plot a 2 x 2 three dimensional figure of scatter based subplots in python to make them evenly spread out across the figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, scatter, scatter3d

These are my configurations using matplotlib for my plotting figures

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax_tl = fig.add_subplot(211, projection='3d')
ax_br = fig.add_subplot(221, projection='3d')
ax_Y0 = fig.add_subplot(212, projection='3d')
ax_Y1 = fig.add_subplot(222, projection='3d')
```

I tried many different combinations of `fig.add_plot()` first argument and drew inspiration from this [document](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/subplot3d.html).

Im currently considering just to plot them separately if its not worth the hassle.

So the question is, how do I plot a 2 x 2 three dimensional figure of  scatter based subplots in python to make them evenly spread out across the figure? My current code makes the plots squished together

Comment: do you mean something like this: [matploblib 2D collections in 3D](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/2dcollections3d.html) ?

Comment: nope, I need to plot a 2 x 2 figure of 3d subplots that is evenly spread out across the figure so as to make it more easily readable. My current code makes the plots squished together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
spec = gridspec.GridSpec(ncols=2, nrows=2, figure=fig)
ax_tl = fig.add_subplot(spec[0, 0], projection='3d')
ax_br = fig.add_subplot(spec[0, 1], projection='3d')
ax_Y0 = fig.add_subplot(spec[1, 0], projection='3d')
ax_Y1 = fig.add_subplot(spec[1, 1], projection='3d')
```